# Modify process name at runtime

Tags: install4j

I have an JFrame-App with multiple instance functionality and I need change process name (task manager) when started it,  because sometime it's necessary kill the process and It is imposible know which is the process that I want to kill, since all of them has the same name (executable name).

Answer (score 1):

The name of a process cannot be changed at runtime. You would have to rename or copy the executable and then start it.